# MakeHuman no running OpenGL error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, opengl

I've read all of the same error post on google, checked my python and opengl files then installed more python stuff (showing pertinent to this problem)

```
python-2.7.12_1 
python3.4-3.4.5_1
python3.5-3.5.2_1  
python-enum34-1.1.6_1 
python3.4-PyQt5-5.6_1 
python3.4-PyQt5-opengl-5.6_1  
python-PyQt5-opengl-5.6_1
python-numpy-1.11.1_1
```

and from source
    PyOpenGL-3.1.1a1

and I am still getting this error when trying to start mankhuman.py

```
NUMPY.VERSION: 1.11.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./makehuman.py", line 827, in <module>
main()
File "./makehuman.py", line 817, in main
from mhmain import MHApplication
File "./core/mhmain.py", line 45, in <module>
import mh
File "./lib/mh.py", line 43, in <module>
from glmodule import grabScreen, hasRenderSkin, renderSkin, getPickedColor, hasRenderToRenderbuffer, renderToBuffer, renderAlphaMask
File "./lib/glmodule.py", line 42, in <module>
import OpenGL
ImportError: No module named OpenGL
```

I am now at a loss as I cannot figure it out.. anyone got an idea that may (will) work?

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: Oh @meepzh ~ Linux Void Linux not a conventual Linux like its not Ubuntututu or debian it is Void Linux :D I had this working before in this Linux but I changed hdd installed it on this hdd and now I forgot what I did, only remember installing a few python from repo and that source openGL and it worked . but now it is not. I know I am missing something, I Just do not remember what.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the packages that provide the OpenGL libraries. Usually these are included in the development or library packages for your graphics card. It doesn't seem like Void Linux installs dependencies for you, so you'll need to install them yourself, and this will depend on the graphics driver you're using. If you use mesa, install `MesaLib-devel`. If you use Nvidia, install `nvidia-libs`. If you use AMD, I don't know what you should install. I'm not familiar with Void Linux so you might need to experiment with variations of the above. Good luck!

Comment: [userx@voided ~]$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30

Comment: What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: just googling and that checking on openGL and I get that error

Comment: This is not an error. You're just giving me what version your graphics card drivers are.

Comment: oh screw it... concider this a waste of your time, go have a coffee... thanks for your help ne ways

Comment: Alright, I hope things work out for ya. Also I'm just gonna recommend using Arch Linux instead, but that's none of my business.

Comment: Yeah somehow I got it to work again. I re-installed my OS to get rid of everything I added ( and did not need in my system) to try and get it to work. then I used the makehuman executable not the one with the py extention, and it showed me some missing dep python errors, so I installed slip (I think it was) and it OpenGL from soure and nimpy and it worked, but not with the mhx2 ext, so I bugged out a bit, then tried a different copy of makehuman that I know that ext worked in, and got it back. I don't know what caused the problem.